# Google crawled my dynamic urls instead of static urls

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I use .htaccess file to convert my dynamic urls to static.

for example:  `doctor.php?id=1 to doctor/firstname-lastname-1`

htaccess ( `RewriteRule ^doctor/([^/]+)/? doctor.php?id=$1 [L]` )

note: firstname and lastname are just keywords and I use the last url element as an ID to fetch the page result.

I have added sitemaps to google. all urls on sitemaps and on the website are static, but I shocked when I saw the result on google. urls are dynamic(ex:`doctor.php?id=1`) instead of static. google should crawl static urls which are on sitemaps and webpages!!

I want the urls appear on google like that way: `doctor/firstname-lastname-1`

Comment: Welcome to SO, kudos for adding your efforts in your question. Regarding your statement `I have added sitemaps to google. all urls on sitemaps and on the website are static, but I shocked when I saw the result on google. urls are dynamic(ex:doctor.php?id=1) instead of static. how can I solve this issue.` Could you please elaborate more on this one with more details.

Comment: sorry bro I'm new here and I need help really, my urls on my website are all statics, but they appear dynamic urls on google engine.

Comment: Something, somewhere and/or at sometime kicked out those dynamic URLs which is what Google found. Maybe there's a canonical link tag or header? As for your htaccess, you might need to add 301 redirects for those old URLs now and Google, over time, will correct to your preferred pattern.

Comment: set the meta tag `Canonical` to tell google what the orginal page is

Comment: bro, there is the meta tag Canonical, but that doesn't work!

Comment: Just so you know, Google can take weeks to recrawl your site, so don't expect immediate changes in the index

Comment: @ChrisHaas just today I submitted my sitemap. now I can see over 200 page appear on google. I just wanna know why google shows dynamic urls ! it's really strange. while there is no dynamic urls on sitemap & the website itself!

Comment: Use a 301 redirect to redirect your dynamic URLs to static ones and resubmit the sitemap

Comment: @AmitVerma please write me htaccess code to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following htaccess code to  301 redirect your dynamic URLs to static .

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} doctor\.php\?id=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /doctor/%1? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^doctor/([^/]+)/? doctor.php?id=$1 [L]
```